# Algorithm for coupled ratio

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there a standard adlgorithm to perform the following operation ?

```
void DifferenceRatioWithNext(std::vector<int> const &v)
{
    for (int i(0); i < v.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << 1 / (v.at(i+1) - v.at(i)) << std::endl; // ERROR !
        // I 'm printing but when complete I'd like to store my results in a container
    }
}
```

I though it'd work fine but when tried to test it, **division by zero** exceptions would pop up (even though `unique` was used in caller):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    // test on 100 random datasets of magnitude=10
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        srand(0);
        for (int i(0); i < 10; ++i) {
            v.push_back(rand()%10);
        } 
        std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
        DifferenceRatioWithNext(v);
        v.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly if I write the error emmiting line like so

```
std::cout << 1 / (double)(v.at(i+1) - v.at(i)) << std::endl; // NO ERROR !
```

my test runs fine

Comment: `std::unique()` does **not** shrink the size of the vector.

Comment: I recommend you read [this `std::unique` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is :

```
std::adjacent_difference(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(result), 
    [](int rhs, int lhs) {
        return 1 / double(rhs-lhs); // attention, lhs is the previous element!
});
```

In this implementation, it's `DifferenceRatioWithPrev` though. **Some remarks**

- You are using integer division, how is that any good for ratio ? (Your results will either be 1 or 0)
- You are not using `unique` correctly, to remove adjacent duplicates do

  ```
  v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
  ```
- The cast to double does not fix your problem, it's only `integer exception by zero` that is thrown automatically. In your case there may be some infinities you haven't noticed